# image changing from the url everyday of the year 365 days

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to display quotes(images) one per each day in two languages (lang1 and lang2) like

> lang1001.png, lang1002.png

and

> lang2001.png, lang2002.png

so on...

This is phoengap HTML mobile app.

also i have a plugin that enables sharing of the image on multiple platforms such as whatsApp,Facebook etc..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function img()
{
var firstJan = Math.floor((new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1))/86400000);
var today = Math.ceil((new Date().getTime())/86400000);
var dayOfYear = today-firstJan;

var bgdImage;
if((dayOfYear+'').length == 1)
bgdImage = '00'+dayOfYear+'.png';
else if((dayOfYear+'').length == 2)
bgdImage = '0'+dayOfYear+'.png';
else
bgdImage = dayOfYear+'.png';

document.getElementById('quotelan1').src = bgdImage;
document.getElementById('quotelan2').src = bgdImage;
}
</script>
```

HTML code for language one :

```
<div class="profile-image" >
            <img id="quotelan1"> 
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('quote of the day', null, 'http://sample.com/quotes/image001.png', 'null')">  
            <i class="material-icons white">share</i> 
            </button> 
          </div>
```

HTML code for language two :

```
 <div class="profile-image" >
                <img id="quotelan2"> 
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('quote of the day', null, 'http://sample.com/quotes/image001.png', 'null')">  
                <i class="material-icons white">share</i> 
                </button> 
              </div>
```

Javascript code works and the language one image displays if i put image in the root folder.

but I've hosted images somewhere on another domain, i don't know how to generate URLs for each image through script.

i want it as something like:

> http://sample.com/quote/imgVariable.png so that i can use in both image src and in the sharing button.

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: Set the string together like: let url = domain + imageName + ending; Similar to the way you did in the img() function

Comment: thank you but how to use this in button url section? that plugin requires a url of image to be placed

Comment: You mean in the onclick handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you set the source of the image elements, prefix the domain name (and any extra Url information)...

```
bgdImage = "http://sample.com/quote/" + bgdImage;
```

That will turn a local file reference into an absolute address so it can be accessed anywhere.

To make the share button work, change the markup for the button to this...

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored"
    onclick="shareQuote()">
```

and add this function to your javascript...

```
function shareQuote() {
    var imageUrl = document.getElementById("quotelan1").src;
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('quote of the day', null, imageUrl, 'null')
}
```

Comment: thank you but how to use this in button url section? that plugin requires a url of image to be placed. ..

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle the button click as well - that should do what you need :)

Comment: Thanks Archer, That worked .. :) appreciate your help